# how to use await inside then callback?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to be able to create a document with the user id once a user has signed up I found out that that best place to do this since it happens only once is when a user has signed up the issue here is it is a await function and the only place I get the user id is in then callback any idea how to syntax this..

```js
const Signup =  (email: string, password: string) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        const docRef = doc(db, 'clients', user.uid);
        const payload = { clients: [] };
        async () => await setDoc(docRef, payload);
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        //const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        if (errorCode === 'auth/weak-password') {
          _miscContext.SetSnackBarMsg(true, 'password must be at least 6 charechters');
        }
        if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          _miscContext.SetSnackBarMsg(true, 'email already exists');
        }
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of `.catch` and `.then` methods is to return another Promise that can be chained.

You can just return it from the callback. If the returned type of the `.then` function is a `Promise` it will be ignored, otherwise, it will be transformed to the Promise, so that's why you can chain `.then` and `.catch` methods

**Also, this question: should I always use asych / await:**

Let's understand what is doing `async` and `await` keywords (you need to understand this, and you will get where and why you need to use them).

`async` - this is just converting your function to async function (you can add `async` to your function and change it to the Promsie`

here is the simple example

```
function example() { return 1; }

console.log(example());   // log: 1
```

with async

```
async function example() { return 1; }

console.log(example());   // log: Promise {<fulfilled>: 1}

// so if the async function is just converting your function to the promise, it means you can get the value by `.then` and `.catch` methods
```

`await` - only uses inside `async` function, and just waiting to the Promise completing and converting the promise to the response

// just dummy example

```
async function example() {
   
   const responseOfPromise =  await Promise.resolve(3);

   return responseOfPromise;
   
}
```

**Usage example of your actual function**

```
const Signup =  (email: string, password: string) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        const docRef = doc(db, 'clients', user.uid);
        const payload = { clients: [] };
       return setDoc(docRef, payload)
      })
      .then((responseOfSetDocFunction) => {
           // and here the callback argument will be returned value from previous then (returned value of setDoc function)
           console.log(responseOfSetDocFunction);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        //const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        if (errorCode === 'auth/weak-password') {
          _miscContext.SetSnackBarMsg(true, 'password must be at least 6 charechters');
        }
        if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          _miscContext.SetSnackBarMsg(true, 'email already exists');
        }
      });
  };
```

Comment: so there is no need to use await in then ?

Comment: I see your point so we chain another then special for the the set doc in this case , is there any place for await or async here ?

Comment: make the whole Signup function be async. wrap your createuser and two thens in a try catch. use the catch logic in the catch clause.

Comment: the other question is should I always use asych / await ? (sorry new to backend)

Comment: Hey @Richardson, no need to use async/await here, this is a just function that is returning a Promsie, but you can call your `Signup(...)` function by await keyword, if you need to do something after

Comment: like this: `async someAPIFunction(.....) {     await Signup(...)   }`,

Comment: @Richardson I have updated the answer, I have included the `async/await` explanation

Comment: @Richardson glad to help